# How to check whether a data exist between a time duration in python postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I am currently developing an application to book rooms. I am using python and database as postgresql. There are multiples rooms are there. When a room is booking room name,start time and end time is stored in database. Next time when the room is booking, the same room shouldn't be able to book for the same time(as booked in previous) duration but should be able to book in other time durations. How to check this condition and do the implementation?